# CKEditor Inlineditor - Select by class instead of ID

Tags: ckeditor

So I have a page with several textareas for a custom form I made. I am able to target an individual textarea by it's ID but I would like to know if theres an easy way to have the CKeditor inline target all textareas elements or have editor select elements by their class instead. At the moment I have setup ID for each other but they are each unique, trying to figure out the best aproach but im not good with javascript and would like some assistance with this.

```
Current code:
<script>
CKEDITOR.inline( 'ID');
</script>
```

Looking for a code that would target all text areas or at lease target class instead of IDs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`CKEDITOR.document.find`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.document-method-find):

```
var elements = CKEDITOR.document.find( '.foo' ),
    i = 0,
    element;

while ( ( element = elements.getItem( i++ ) ) ) {
    CKEDITOR.inline( element );
}
```

You can also use the official [jQuery adapter](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_jquery):

```
$( '.foo' ).ckeditor( function() { 
    // Callback function code.
}, { 
    // Config options here
} );
```

Comment: Is there a way to target all textareas to use inline using the Jquery adapter method?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
$(".ckeditor").each(function () {
         CKEDITOR.replace( $(this).attr("name") );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This sample shows how to automatically replace all `<textarea>` elements of a given class with a CKEditor instance.

To replace a `<textarea>` element, simply assign it the `ckeditor` class, as in the code below:

```
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.11.4/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>

<textarea class="ckeditor" name="editor1"></textarea>
<textarea class="ckeditor" name="editor2"></textarea>
<textarea class="" name="editor3"></textarea>
```

Note that other  attributes (like id or name) need to be adjusted to your document.

[ckeditor replacebyclass](https://ckeditor.com/latest/samples/old/replacebyclass.html)